# TypeLoadException in Universal App using IKVM converted library

Tags: java, c#, win-universal-app, ikvm, typeloadexception

Im using a library written in Java which uses `common-math3` library from Apache. I have a Universal Windows App need to use above library, so my choice is to use IKVM for converting the library into a .Net dll.

I converted the library into the dll, and successfully used it in Windows Form and WPF application with .Net 4.6.1 platform without any errors. 
However when using in Universal App, the `System.TypeLoadException` occurred when I call the function from library. More detail the function I called is a constructor with parameter

```
public Ctor(double  x[][], double y[])
```

Im not sure the error occurred because of type compatibility b/w Java and .Net, but I used double[][], and double[] type in .Net for above call.

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Thanks